# Using Console/Curl how could I click on elements to trigger click()

Tags: javascript, automation, accessibility

I have a couple weblinks of example places to trigger mouse clicks and keyboard entry.

When I try

```
document.getElementById("foobar").click()
```

in firefox console I get null error

I am trying to trigger inputs like at tiny. cc/oiclick
tiny. cc/oiclick1
tiny. cc/oiclick2

I cannot even get tab spacebar or enter to work since theres no event scan for 13 or 31 keypress

one solution is this tiny.cc/oiclick4

the element is named "null" in the inpector so i think this causes null error

Comment: You get a null error because that id does not exist.

Comment: javascript says its optimized so it exists but only the moment of button click mouse event => click